# Inner Active add Api with QML

Tags: qt, addition, qml, ads

I am trying to get the inner active add Api to work with QML. I have found this Nokia example: http://projects.developer.nokia.com/fifteenpuzzle on how to do it. I plan to just use the add widget they use in my own app but when I compile the app it gives this error: "'KErrNone' was not declared in this scope" on anything excpet Symbian and once it runs on Symbian the add area is just black and after a while I get this error: "AdBannerWidget::onNetworkError =  "Error downloading http://cdn1.inner-active.mobi/mnt/InnerActive/Resources/USAGC/eng_pic.gif - server replied: Not Found"".

Please help I have no idea what could be causing this, it's probably something stupid but I really need help.

I also get a error while trying to design the qml because of it not being able to "import Analytics 1.0"

I do have a inner active account and I have tried it using my own tag they generated for me but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My name is Nirit and I'm a support manager at inneractive.

we just released our new Beta QML open-sourced project, it is now available on your Dashboard (the SDKs tab).
Please download the .zip file and take the time to read through our clear and concise documentation.

If you have any questions or comments, please don't hesitate to contact me.
Nirit (nirit@inner-active.com).

Answer (score 0):

For the black widget and network error, I bet you have to register first with [inneractive](http://console.inner-active.com/iamp/publisher/register?ref_id=Nokia) to get an actual account.

"KErrNone" seems indeed symbian only. Might be that the project is just no meant to compiled on desktop as such. You maybe would have to `#ifdef Q_OS_SYMBIAN` some parts of it.

Comment: When I try the url, I indeed receive a 404 (not found) but with some xml content, telling me "no such key". I don't know the api, but you probably have to specify your key somewhere in the request (header? cookie? url query param?)